# how to use SharedPreferences outside of oncreate?

Tags: java, android, function, sharedpreferences, android-context

How to use `SharedPreferences` in a class without `oncreate` ?

I get null pointer when accessing it.

```
  public class Ftr extends Activity 

   { 
    SharedPreferences preferences;

    Context ab=this;

  public void ft()
     {
       preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ab);
      String result = preferences.getString("F","");
        }
      }
```

I'm calling Function `ft()` from another activity `Ftr` is just a class not an activity.

How can I use `SharedPreferences` in this condition?

Comment: You need to create an static method which takes Context as parameter and call that method from non-activity class. Better way is to write that method into some utility class (NOT in activity)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take in  Common method or Utils So  use in All Method.

```
  public static void SaveInPreference(Context mContext, String key, String objString) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mContext.getSharedPreferences(mContext.getString(R.string.app_name),
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString(key, objString);
    editor.commit();
}

public static String getPrefString(Context mContext, final String key, final String defaultStr) {
    SharedPreferences pref = mContext.getSharedPreferences(mContext.getString(R.string.app_name),
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return pref.getString(key, defaultStr);
}
```